# Cómo quitar y poner permisos a los objetos de SQL Server a usuarios del dominio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo el siguiente escenario: un dominio con WServer 2012 R2 y un SQL Server 2012. En el SQL hay un inicio de sesión para todos los usuarios del dominio, `MI_DOMINIO\Usuarios del Dominio`. Se ejecuta en los PCs una aplicación Access que se conecta a la BBDDs por ODBC con origen de datos creado en el Administrador de datos ODBC con conexión "Con la autenticación de Windows NT...".

Ahora mi pregunta ¿ puedo quitar o poner permisos mediante GRANT y DENY a los objetos del SQL Server, o quitarlo/agregarlo de/a un determinado rol a un usuario en concreto, por ejemplo `MI_DOMINIO\Pepe`, aunque este miembro del dominio no esté explícitamente definido en "Inicios de sesión". ?, gracias